# How to delete row in access using JOption Pane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
Error Message>  Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression.
```

What i should do? what/where going to be get?
i got problems i try the DELETE * and DELETE only but those not really works

```
  int student;
  student = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ENTER STUDENT NUMBER :"));
  try{


   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Seatwork");
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery("DELETE  FROM Seatwork where StudentNo= '"+studentTxt.getText()+"'");

}catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

}

Comment: You should really consider using a `PreparedStatement` to prevent from SQL injection

Comment: what PreparedStament?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

1) If `studentTxt.getText()` is an integer,

Do not wrap `studentTxt.getText()` into single quotes.

Use it like:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery("DELETE  FROM Seatwork where StudentNo= "+studentTxt.getText()+"");
```

2)
Replace `createStatement()` with this

```
Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: Syntax Error(Missing operator) in query expression

Comment: _"If studentTxt.getText() is an integer, Do not wrap studentTxt.getText() into single quotes."_. Not just that, but if it is an integer, it should be parsed.

Comment: may be  studentTxt.getText() is empty.

Comment: parsing isn't necessary if you put studentTxt.getText() into double quotes.

Comment: my student.getText is only add in database
i use InputMsgDialog for get the student number to my database and delete but i got a problem for Missing Operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a main type and null, before the text in your JOption Pane statements.

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
```

and a

```
    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ENTER STUDENT NUMBER :"));
```

That should help.